# How to query a timestamp in SQL Server 2008 with Linq-to-Entities?

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I've got a `timestamp` column in SQL Server 2008.

Now I need to query that column by using a date that picks up from a calendar server control.

We assume that I got a DateTime dt object;

I need to filter by this datetime object that returns all the records logged on that date(dt).

```
   var a = DateTime.Now.ToString();
   var IsDone = from d in _le.diets
                 where d.log_time.Contains(a)
                 select d.done;
```

_le is a private entity framework object.

This code has problem:

> Error 3   'byte[]' does not contain a
>   definition for 'Contains' and the best
>   extension method overload
>   'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Contains(System.Linq.ParallelQuery,
>   TSource)' has some invalid
>   arguments f:\tests\diet\diet\DataTier\DietMovieRepository.cs  30  32  diet
>
> Error 2   Cannot convert lambda
>   expression to type 'string' because it
>   is not a delegate
>   type  f:\tests\diet\diet\DataTier\DietMovieRepository.cs  30  26  diet
>
> Error 1   Delegate
>   'System.Func'
>   does not take 1
>   arguments f:\tests\diet\diet\DataTier\DietMovieRepository.cs  30  26  diet
>
> Error 4   Instance argument: cannot
>   convert from 'byte[]' to
>   'System.Linq.ParallelQuery'   f:\tests\diet\diet\DataTier\DietMovieRepository.cs  30  32  diet

I'm a EF beginner, thanks for your help!

**UPDATE**

IN EF cs file

I see

```
   public static diet Creatediet(global::System.Int64 id, global::System.Boolean done, global::System.Byte[] log_time)
        {
            diet diet = new diet();
            diet.id = id;
            diet.done = done;
            diet.log_time = log_time;
            return diet;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A SQL Server "timestamp" has nothing to do with time (in fact the name "timestamp" is now marked deprecated; "rowversion" is identical and should be used instead).

If you truly have a "timestamp" this is not possible. If you have a datetime set to the insertion time, it should be trivial:

```
DateTime start = date.Date, end = start.AddDays(1);

...
where row.log_time >= start && row.log_time < end
...
```

Also, if you are mainly doing date-range searches, log_time may be a fair candidate for the clustered index. Or if you are doing day-based queries a non-clustered index on an integer that is the days-into-epoch would work too.

Comment: 2016 now and EntityFramework still uses timestamp when you generate a table with a rowversion

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to look at just the date part of it? Then you should be able to do something like:

```
   var a = DateTime.Now;
   var isDone = from d in _le.diets
                 where d.log_time.Date == a.Date
                 select d.done;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it looks that I can't get d.log_time.Date. Because log_time is a timestamp in database.

Comment: Oh ok, whats the type of log_time? Is it a TimeSpan?

Comment: I meant in the model. It generates as Binary. I'm not sure how you would query against that sorry. :(